# i have to be confirmed that static features of a class are inherited Or not

Tags: java

i have tried

```
class A

{

public static void main(String a[])

{

System.out.println(12);

}

}

class B extends A

{


}
```

then i executed class B

```
 output -12
```

it is only possible if static main method is being inherited

but i am confused that static features are inherited or not?

Comment: You didn't execute class `B`. Also, how was the output `-12` when you printed `12`? Was that a typo?

Comment: i think u should try .                                                                       i have already tried

Comment: class B is being executed please tell me reason behind it.

Comment: Class `B` **isn't** being executed. It doesn't have anything to execute. The entrance point to a program is defined to be `public static void main(String[] args)`, and if that's in class `A` then you are starting execution in class `A`.

Comment: B is extending the class A   .but code was same as above and i launch the application as " java B "                                                                                         thanx

Comment: That doesn't change anything. `B` isn't being executed. The program enters through class `A`.

Comment: This is easily confirmable by placing `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new RuntimeException().getStackTrace()));` into `main()` and seeing that `main()` is being executed from `A`

Comment: @user3580294 Class B will inherit the main method from class A, so what Anoop claims is true.  However the output shouldn't be -12, I suspect there should be a space in-between them!

Comment: @ConMan The method is inherited as in it's accessible from `B`, but it will still be executed from `A`, not `B`, as a stack trace shows.

Comment: I think part of the issue here is that exactly what "inherited" means is a bit vague... `static` methods are indeed *accessible* from subclasses, but they don't follow the same rules for overriding/etc. as instance methods/fields do.

Comment: thanx i got ur point.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly static stuff is inherited.

Add

```
public static void x(){
System.out.println( "foo" );
}
```

to A and

```
B.x();
```

to main, compile and run like this

```
$ java B
```

or

```
$ java A
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes Static fields and methods are inherited.

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    A.num = 2;
    System.out.println(A.num);
    System.out.println(B.num);
    B.num = 3;
    System.out.println(A.num);
    System.out.println(B.num);
 }
}

class A{
    public static int num;
}

class B extends A{

}
```

Result will be:
2
2
3
3

Say num is tracking number of objects of type A(by incrementing itself in the constructor), and objects of type B is also of type A then this will give the same result for A & B (i.e. A.num & B.num) as shown in the output.

Lets say we change the code to

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    A.num = 2;
    System.out.println(A.num);
    System.out.println(B.num);
    B.num = 3;
    System.out.println(A.num);
    System.out.println(B.num);
 }
}

class A{
    public static int num;
}

class B extends A{
    public static int num;
}
```

Output is 
2
0
2
3

Here our A.num can be used to track number of objects of type A(and by extension of type B), and B.num can be used to track number of objects of type B only(not for A).

To be clear, yes static fields and methods are inherited. But if you decide to hide the inherited member by using field of same name, then you will access new member, not inherited member.

For more info check [Hiding methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)

Comment: Interestingly, from what I'm reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898097/what-are-the-rules-dictating-the-inheritance-of-static-variables-in-java), the calls to `B.num` would actually be compiled to `A.num`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. Yes it seems that call gets changed to A.num from B.num, but only if you are not using a newer member.

Comment: Newer member as in not hiding the original member? Yeah, that sounds about right. Wasn't the case when I originally posted that, but now that you have a lot more stuff in your answer I think that being more specific originally would have helped...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused with inheritance and overriding. Static methods are inherited but they cannot be overriden. All methods except private ones are inherited. Visit this link [here](http://javaingrab.blogspot.com/2012/09/is-it-possible-to-override-static.html) which I think will clear your doubts

Comment: If you're going to just link OP elsewhere, it's better to post the link as a comment. Answers should be able to stand on their own, regardless of whether there is a link present.