# Cannot access Parent LinkedList java

Tags: java, inherited

I have parent class CompositeDiscount. It has a linkedlist to store some dicount.
It has two child class BestForVersityStrategy and BestForStudentStrategy. I populate parent linked list in another class Registration. When I try to iterate LL from UI it gives the discount list but when i call it from child (i.e BestForVersity) it shows the list is empty.

```
package registrationui;
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class CompositeDiscount implements IDiscountStrategy{
    LinkedList<IDiscountStrategy> disList;
    public CompositeDiscount(){
        disList= new LinkedList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getDiscount(Registration reg) {
       return 0;
    }
    public void addDiscount(IDiscountStrategy ids){
        disList.add(ids);
    }
}
```

this is parent class

```
package registrationui;
public class BestForStudentStrategy extends CompositeDiscount{


     public int getDisocunt(Registration reg){
        int amount=0;
        for(IDiscountStrategy ids:disList){
           if(ids.getDiscount(reg)>amount){
               amount=ids.getDiscount(reg);
           }
        }
        return amount;
    } 
}
```

this is child class

```
private void academicActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

      if(academic.isSelected())
        rcc.addCompositeDiscount(rcc.getDiscountPloicy("registrationui.AcademicExcellenceDiscount"));
        else{
            for(IDiscountStrategy ids:rcc.getCompositeDisocunt().disList)
            {
                if(ids.getClass().toString().equals("class registrationui.AcademicExcellenceDiscount"))
                    rcc.getCompositeDisocunt().disList.remove(ids);
            }
        }
    }
```

UI from where it id populated via controller that call Resitration class

```
public void addCompositeDiscount(IDiscountStrategy ids){        
       cds.addDiscount(ids);
       bfn=new BestForNsuStrategy();      
       bfs=new BestForStudentStrategy();  
    }
```

```
public IDiscountStrategy getDiscountPolicy(String policy){
        try {
            try {
                ids=(IDiscountStrategy)Class.forName(policy).newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Registration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Registration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Registration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return ids;
    }
```

Comment: As answered below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898097/what-are-the-rules-dictating-the-inheritance-of-static-variables-in-java as answered below.

Answer (score 1):

Your linked list in CompositeDiscount is static. Static variables in Java are not inherited, they exist only in the class which declares them

Comment: Sorry it was not static. like now . I have updated code please check now.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static LinkedList<IDiscountStrategy> disList;
```

you must user public modifier for static

Comment: it is not static

Comment: you must user public modifier to access that