# On Java statics and their access modifiers

Tags: java, static, access-modifiers

If static members are not inherited in Java then why access modifiers (private, protected…) are applicable to them?

Perhaps, I’m not 100% clear on the term “inherited”: 
when they say “statics not inherited” do they mean “not visible” or “can not be redefined/reimplemented” or both?

Would it be correct to say that access modifiers imply only visibility when speaking about static class members, and visibility as well as reimplementation possibility when speaking about regular class members?

Can you please provide examples when making static, say, private makes sense?

Thanks

PS: Now I think that the statement "Static variables in Java are not inherited, they exist only in the class which declares them" spread here and there and around on this forum (for instance: [What are the rules dictating the inheritance of static variables in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898097/what-are-the-rules-dictating-the-inheritance-of-static-variables-in-java)) IS NOT correct as

The Java Language Specification #8.4.8 states:

8.4.8 Inheritance, Overriding, and Hiding

A class C inherits from its direct superclass all concrete methods m (both static and instance) of the superclass for which all of the following are true:

m is a member of the direct superclass of C.
m is public, protected, or declared with package access in the same package as C.
No method declared in C has a signature that is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of m.

Comment: `private` simply means that it cannot be accessed from outside the class. That applies just as much to static members as to instance members.

Answer (score 2):

> If static members are not inherited in Java then why access modifiers
>   (private, protected…) are applicable to them?

Who said that static members cannot be inhertied, refer following [JLS (§Example 8.2-2). example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#d5e11809)

In Java being "**static**" simply means that there is no object required to access this field/method.

"**private**" is just an access modifier which means that following field/method cannot be accessed outside of its, and can only accessed by this class itself or any inner class.

Only thing with "static" methods of a superclass inherited in subclass can be read understood from below excerpt from JLS:

> If a class C declares or inherits a static method m, then m is said to
>   hide any method m', where the signature of m is a subsignature
>   (§8.4.2) of the signature of m', in the superclasses and
>   superinterfaces of C that would otherwise be accessible to code in C.

**So, basically you cannot override a static method but you can certainly inherit a static method, if it is not hidden by subclass.**

Read following [JLS section (§8.4.8.2. Hiding (by Class Methods))](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.2) about hiding of class methods.

Also, you can read Java's inheritance tutorial from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) and below is a screen shot of summary from same page

[image]

Comment: ... AND HIDING MEANS, I believe, that if static method is redefined in subclass then polymorphism does not work - which version is called is defined by the type of the reference variable and not by the actual object type

Comment: @AndreyM.Stepanov You got it.

Comment: Well, `static` methods declared in an `interface` are not inherited, but that’s the only exception and it’s a new rule as `static` methods in `interface`s are possible since Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Member visibility doesn't *just* apply to child classes.  [From Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html), they apply, in reference to a `static` member, to the rest of the package, or the rest of the "world".

If you create a `private static` member, you're stating that this is a member *exclusive* to that specific class.  You then work your way up the visibility chain:

- `private` is least visible,
- `<no modifier>` (or package-protected) is second-least visible,
- `protected` is second-most visible, and
- `public` is most visible.

I've not seen anyone really use a `protected static` member, even though it's valid Java.  Convention dictates that this should be a visible constant (in that case it's likely `public`), or a less-than visible constant for test exposure (which would justify package-protected visibility.

Comment: A `protected static` member can be useful, e.g., for a nested class used by subclasses for some implementation task.

Answer (score 0):

A `static` member in a class simply means that it will be shared across all the objects of the class. A new variable won't be instantiated for every instance of the class.

Access modifiers control the visibility of variables in Java. The meaning of the access modifiers is the same for static as well as non-static members. It has nothing to do with static members only.

With respect to your question, the use of access modifiers in static variables means the following:

`private static count`: The static member count is only visible to the class defining it. However, if you inherit the class defining this static variable, your inherited class cannot directly access it. `count` can be accessed only if super class has a `getter` defined for it, or if the access modifier is changed to `public` or `protected.`

Comment: As it turns out a static member class is not only shared by all instances of the class but can also be accessed by any child class ... if access level does not restrict the visibility

Comment: Yes. Check this out: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: "Static fields are associated with the class, rather than with any object. Every instance of the class shares a class variable, which is in one fixed location in memory."

Comment: "As it turns out", a static member type obeys the same accessibility and inheritance rules as other static members. So `private` members are not inherited, package-private only by subclasses in the same package, and the other levels are inherited.