# Multiple inheritance quagmire - which class is instantiated?

Tags: java, multiple-inheritance, undefined-behavior, auto-value

Supposing I have the following classes:

```
abstract class A {
    static abstract class _Foo {}
}

class B extends A {
    static void doSomething() {
        System.out.println(C.saySomething());
    }

    static _Foo getInner() {
        return new C._Foo();
    }

    static abstract class _Foo extends A._Foo {}
}

final class C extends D {
    static String saySomething() {
        return "Something";
    }
}

abstract class D {
    static class _Foo extends B._Foo {
        public int value() {
            return 42;
        }
    }
}
```

To provide some context:

- All of these classes reside in the same package.
- Class `C` and `D` are generated at compile time
- Class `A` as well as `C` are never instantiated; they simply provide some behaviour for class `B`
- Class `B` is the only one that is actually used.
- Class `D` is unknown until after compile time, which is why we are only using `C` in `B`.

This is similar to what one might expect when working with [`google autovalue`](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value)

---

My question is with regards to the `getInner` function in `B`:

1. Which `_Foo` will be instantiated at the line `return new C._Foo();`? The `_Foo` in `D` or the one in `A`?
2. Is this undefined behaviour as to which gets instantiated or is it documented? *Please provide documentation if possible*
3. How is the order determined?

*The last question is just as an FYI, I'm mostly interested in the first two.*

Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898097/what-are-the-rules-dictating-the-inheritance-of-static-variables-in-java

Comment: Did you try it? What did you find?

Comment: @JimGarrison I will once I get a chance to, but I was mostly asking to see if someone has a link to some documentation that describes this behaviour. Even if I find out which one is instantiated, I still need to know if I am relying on undefined behaviour or not

Comment: I am not sure how you could imaging getting an A._Foo on that line - you've explicitly qualified the expression to be `new C._Foo()` - so it has to be the _Foo that is exposed through C, which has to be the one from D... (though I confess I expected the compile to complain that there was no _Foo explicitly in C...)

Comment: @moilejter, that makes sense. I don't know what I was thinking yesterday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your three questions...

1. An instance of the `_Foo` in `D` will be returned from `new C._Foo()`.
2. No, it isn't; the `_Foo`s are "members" of the classes they are declared in, so they are inherited much like variables. (In this case, like static variables.) [Spec] (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.2). (This is the best documentation I could muster up.)
3. The order is determined by what is immediately inherited by class `C`. Since `C` extends `D`, `C` will inherit whatever `D` has (i.e. `D._Foo`). If `D` didn't declare a class called `_Foo`, then `D` would inherit `B`'s `_Foo`, and then `C` would inherit that.

Hope this helps. :)