# How fields are added from interface to class in Java?

Tags: java, interface

```
interface Z{ int x = 10;}

Class A implements Z{}

Class B implements Z{}
```

How java use x in this case?

Does java generate single copy of x, because x is static final?
Or different copies for Class A and Class B?

Comment: Would be easy to test! Try it.

Comment: Possibly related: [What are the rules dictating the inheritance of static variables in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898097/what-are-the-rules-dictating-the-inheritance-of-static-variables-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As JLS says [about static fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.1):

> If a field is declared static, there exists exactly one incarnation of
>   the field, no matter how many instances (possibly zero) of the class
>   may eventually be created.

About [fields inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3):

> A class inherits from its direct superclass and direct superinterfaces
>   all the non-private fields of the superclass and superinterfaces that
>   are both accessible to code in the class and not hidden by a
>   declaration in the class.

There is no special case about static fields inheritance, so they have to be inherited too.

We cannot write a good representative code sample with an interface, because of its variables are implicitly declared as static final. So, let's write a sample with superclass. Say we have:

```
class Base {
    static int x = 15;
}

class A extends Base {}

class B extends Base {}
```

The `x` variable is shared part of `Base` class. If we think about inheritance in terms of IS-A relationship, then `A` (or `B`) is `Base`. Then `x` is shared part of `A`, `B` and `Base`. And simple demo:

```
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(A.x++);
        System.out.println(B.x);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
15
16
```

As you can see, superclass shares a static variable with subclasses. And with an interface actually nothing changes.

Comment: You might want to update your JLS links to the current version (12). Just a very minor note though.

Comment: @Zabuza I'm little behind the times ) Thanks, updated.